# Angular ng2-charts x axis label format

Tags: angular, date, ng2-charts

I have a angular code using ng2-charts library, and would like to format X axis label data depending on the filter option.

If I choose the filter option to be last day/last month/other interval < 1 year, the middletier will send data points to the front end in unix format, and the chart X axis label should display data in format 'DD Month, HH:mm am' or 'DD Month, HH:mm pm'. Example: 3 Aug, 3:12 am, 2 Sep, 5:00 pm

If the user choose the filter option to be last year/more than one year, the chart X axis label should display data in format 'Month DD, YYYY'. Example: Jan 3, 2019

I have tried the following but it does not work, and it doesn't convert the time to 12 hour format in am or pm.

```
scales: {
    xAxes: [{
        display: true,
        type: 'time',
        time: {
            displayFormats: {
                'millisecond': 'DD MM, HH:mm',
                'second': 'DD Month, HH:mm',
                'minute': 'DD Month, HH:mm',
                'hour': 'DD Month, HH:mm',
                'day': 'DD Month, HH:mm',
                'week': 'DD Month, HH:mm',
                'month': 'DD Month, HH:mm',
                'quarter': 'DD Month, HH:mm',
                'year': 'Month DD, YYYY'
            }
            parser: 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm'
        }
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution

```
 scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            display: true,
            type: 'time',
            distribution: 'series',
            gridLines: {
                display: true
            },
            time: {
                displayFormats: {
                    millisecond: 'D MMM, h:mm a',
                    second: 'D MMM, h:mm a',
                    minute: 'D MMM, h:mm a',
                    hour: 'D MMM, h:mm a',
                    day: 'D MMM, h:mm a',
                    week: 'll',
                    month: 'll',
                    quarter: 'll',
                    year: 'll'
                },
            },
            ticks: {
                autoSkip: true,
                maxTicksLimit: 15
            }
        }],
```